# Data contained in an array/json, want to inject into page via DOM, does jQ have templates?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, templates

Say I have an array, that contains data that I want to display in a html table. (sort of how gmail has all the data in js objects)

I have this data in an array so I can do ajax type operations like updating/deleting/sorting of the data.

Does jQuery have templates where I can create a template for a given row, and then just loop through my javascript array/json object and then inject the row into the table?

this is a common pattern, but I don't have any experience with it so I am looking for the best practice.  I know people use templates for this.

Answer (score 3):

There is a jQuery plugin available for this called jTemplates. You can get it [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jTemplates). I also dug up [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552934/what-javascript-templating-engine-do-you-recommend) SO question which lists some other alternatives you may want to consider.